# Can't get the 3 DIV's to be next to each other inside container

Tags: html, css

I am new to making websites so I started creating one just for practice but I already came across a problem.  I cannot get the 3 .mainContain div's to be next to each other inside the container.  I already tried setting them as inline-block and already tried floating them left and clearing them; the width is also a small enough size to make them all fit.

Thanks for your help.

```css
body{
 background: white;
}
/***********************************
NAV
************************************/
#container{
 max-width: 1000px;
 margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
 width: 100%;
 height: 900px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
#nav{
 border: 1px solid blue;
 width: 90%;
 height: 50px;
 margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
#navholder ul li{
 list-style: none;
 text-align: center;
}
#navholder ul li a{
 text-decoration: none;
 float: left;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 10px;
}
#navholder{
 width: 35%;
 height: 40px;
 margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
 display: block;
 border: 1px solid green;
}
/***********************************
MAIN CONTAIN
************************************/
.mainContain{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 25%;
 height: 650px;
 float: left;
 margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
 border: 1px solid red;
}
/***********************************
LEFT
************************************/
#left{

}
/***********************************
CENTER
************************************/
#center{
clear: both;
}
/***********************************
RIGHT
************************************/
#right{
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE.html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Get Me Coding</title>
    <link href="helpwebsite.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="nav">
        <div id="navHolder">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- this closes the Nav Holder DIV -->
    </div>
    <!-- this closes the NAV DIV -->
    <div id="container">
        <section>
            <div class="mainContain" id="left">
                <div id="leftContainer"></div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">What To Practice</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Web Pages To Practice</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">How did I practice</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- this closes the first MAIN CONTAIN -->
    </div>
    <!-- this closes the LEFT DIV -->
    <div class="mainContain" id="center"></div>
    <!-- this closes the second MAIN CONTAIN -->
    <div class="mainContain" id="right"></div>
    <!-- this closes the third MAINCONTAIN -->
    </section>
    </div>
    <!-- This closes the container DIV -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried <div id="container" horizontal layout>

Comment: You don't have 3 such divs inside a container. You have two of them as siblings and another two levels down inside other elements. You realize that widths are often calculated from parent element size, right?

Comment: your DOM is not okeay.. to do what you wanna do.. it is a mess.. can you paint how the containers need to be.. i will help you now or tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

Try floating them all to the left to get them to align next to each other.
https://jsfiddle.net/LLztwjmg/

```
.mainContain{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
    height: 650px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
/***********************************
LEFT
************************************/
#left{
    float:left;
}
/***********************************
CENTER
************************************/
#center{
    float:left;
}
/***********************************
RIGHT
************************************/
#right{
    float: left;
}
```